# webService request failed with HTTP status 404

Tags: asp.net, web-services, http-status-code-404

I have problem with sending a big file via webService (System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse).

Everything works fine when the file is smaller then 20 MB, if it's bigger i get a response with 404 code.

**Exception Information**

```
Exception Type: System.Net.WebException
Status: ProtocolError
Response: System.Net.HttpWebResponse
Message: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: System.Object[] ReadResponse(System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapClientMessage, System.Net.WebResponse, System.IO.Stream, Boolean)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: System.Web.Services
```

**StackTrace Information**

```
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at ie.osds.DocumentsTransferBLL.FSDMZRepositoryService.FileStreamingWebService.UploadScanning(DateTime DateCreated, String Title, String FileName, String ReferenceNumber, String Author, String DocumentType, XmlNode IndexData, Byte[] Content, Nullable`1 IsCompressed, Nullable`1 Version, DateTime DateReceived, String CreatedBy, String OrigDocumentGUID)
   at ie.osds.DocumentsTransferBLL.Actions.ActionsHelper.UploadDocumentToDMZFileStreaming(FileStreamingWebService fsDMZWebService, SPQDocument spqDocument, String documentReferenceNumber, String documentAuthor, String documentType, Byte[] documentContent, String version, DateTime dateReceived)
   at ie.osds.DocumentsTransferBLL.Actions.DocumentsUploadAction.Upload()*
```

Comment: Can you post some of the failing code?

Comment: a the moment i can't because i only get logged error message and i try to resolve it. This should by a simply File Streaming Web Service and used method update.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your file upload is timing out:

**You can trap this error in your global.asax to see if this is the case:**

```
Protected Sub Application_EndRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Context
    If Not IsNothing(context) Then

        If Not context.Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then

            'Detect file upload exceeded max length:
            If context.Response.StatusCode = 404 And
                context.Response.SubStatusCode = 13 Then
                'clear the previous error page content:
                context.Response.Clear()
                'redirect to custom error page:
                context.Server.Transfer("~/error.aspx?code=404.13", False)
            End If

        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

**You can also increase the request length in your web.config like so:**

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="29296" />
</system.web>
```

Note: Value is in Kbytes

Answer (score 0):

If there is a webservice reference in web application just delete that then Rebuild,run the webservice and then again add that webservice reference to the web application.